# Remove % sign according to condition in React

Tags: reactjs, redux, slice, trim

I want to remove Percentage symbol from a textbox during submission of the form. This is the piece of code I am using right now. But it is not working?

```
values.ORSalesAndPurchaseSalesPrice=(values.ItemType ==="8") ? values.ORSalesAndPurchaseSalesPrice.slice('%'):values.ORSalesAndPurchaseSalesPrice;
```

Shall I use `trim()` or `slice()`. If so what is the right syntax?

Comment: did you check what does this return ( values.ItemType ==="8" ) is it returning true ?

Comment: have you tried replace, or replaceAll?

Comment: @Praveen Rao Chavan.G Yes it is returning "8". Is my syntax correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this...
Simple illustration.

```js
var str = 'Hello%World%!This%Is$Test'.replace(/[%\s]/g, '');
console.log(str);
```